# Why isn't node.js shown in chrome developer tools?

Tags: node.js

I'm just learning node.js so forgive me for the naivete. So I create a JavaScript file to put all my node methods in and then link it to an html file. I run the html file and look in the JavaScript console only to get "Uncaught ReferenceError". My code executes completely fine on windows powershell, but not in chrome developer tools. Why is this?

Comment: node.js is a language meant to be run in a server context, not in a browser

Comment: You can find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424672/newbie-javascript-vs-node-js) helpful. Essentially, Node.js runs server-side Javascript code. HTML and Chrome Developer Tools run client-side Javascript code.

Comment: But is there a way to put data that you get from node.js into the browser?

Comment: @Paine8887, you can create an API in Node.js that serves your data and makes it available to the client. Frameworks, such as [Express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) or [Koa](https://github.com/koajs/koa), can help you create your server.

Comment: Are you asking how to debug node with Chrome, because you should run with `node --inspect-brk index.js` if you want that. Node APIs aren't available in a browser "page" context.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is a browser.  It runs Javascript in a browser context.

Node.js is a stand-alone Javascript environment meant for running Javascript in a server environment or for stand-alone tool development.

node.js does not do HTML display like a browser and does not support the same "host" environment that a browser does with host objects such as `window` and `document`.  Similarly node.js adds all sorts of modules to the run-time environment that are not present in a browser such as the `fs` module for accessing files or the `process` module for accessing the system.

Both node.js and Chrome use the same V8 Javascript engine internally for parsing and running plain Javascript, but each puts its own environment around that engine that give them different purposes and capabilities.

> o I create a JavaScript file to put all my node methods in and then link it to an html file. I run the html file and look in the JavaScript console only to get "Uncaught ReferenceError".

If you have an HTML file with Javascript `<script>` tags in it, you would have to use that in a browser (such as Chrome), not in node.js.

If you had just a plain Javascript file who's job it was to start a server and listen for incoming connections, you would use that in node.js, not in Chrome.

> My code executes completely fine on windows powershell, but not in chrome developer tools. Why is this?

We could advise more completely if you showed your actual code, but it seems likely that you've written your Javascript to use some of the node.js libraries that are only present in node.js and are not present in a browser environment.  As such that is a node.js program (written in Javascript), not a script that can run in a browser environment.

---

For an analogy, imagine you had two tools that each had the C language built into them.  One included the standard library that many of us have used.  Another did not include that library, but instead included a very different library.  While they both have the C language at their core, the headers and libraries they come with are completely different and thus code written in one tool using its libraries would not run in the other tool that had different libraries.

That's similar to Chrome vs. node.js.  Each as the Javascript language at their core, but each come with a different set of libraries.

If you write some pure Javascript that doesn't use any external libraries such as:

```
 function square(x) {
     return x * x;
 }
```

That code will run in either Javascript environment (Chrome or node.js) because it's nothing but pure Javascript and does not rely on any libraries outside the standard Javascript implementation.

But, if you write some code that uses the `fs` library such as:

```
 const fs = require('fs');

 function countLines(filename) {
     let data = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
     return data.split('/n').length;
 }
```

That code needs the `fs` library.  That library exists in node.js, not in Chrome (or any browser) and as such will only work in node.js.

Or, if you write some code that uses objects that are browser-specific such as `document`:

```
 function getHeadline() {
     let obj = document.getElementById("headline");
     return obj.textContent;
 }
```

This code would run in a browser, but not in node.js because it relies on the `document` external object which is only supplied by a browser implementation, not by node.js.

---

If what you're really trying to do is to get access (within a web page) so data that a node.js program can supply (such as getting data from a database), then what you would typically do is to make your node.js program into a web server (often using the Express toolkit).  You can then make Ajax requests from the Javascript in the web page to your remote server to fetch data and bring it back into the web page.

Comment: I'm a new user to this site. would you like me to copy and paste my JavaScript file with the node.js inside so you can look at it?

Comment: here's a link to the code itself.https://github.com/bloodwolf616/nodeCode/blob/master/Desktop/experimental%20code/commandLine.js

Comment: @Paine8887 - Yes, normally you would paste a representative sample of the code you're asking about in your question and format it appropriately with the `{}` button in the stackoverflow question editor.  Questions here about code should include the code you're asking about. The code you show in the link uses the `https` module which is uniquely present in node.js, not in Chrome.  That type of code would be written with an Ajax call in Chrome (using the `fetch()` interface).  But, `fetch()` is an interface that comes in a browser and the `https` module is a node.js module.

Comment: So in the browser if I wanted to get information from another site I would something AJAX. The https module is specifically for node.js which is outside the browser. I guess my next question would be how can nodejs be useful to the user if it outside the browser? From my lessons they said node.js is useful because it is non-blocking and can handle many system events at a time.

Comment: side note: I've tried the {} , but every time i copy and past my code it doesn't come out right. If there is a post explaining how to use all the tools in the question bar that would be helpful.

Comment: @Paine8887 - You can read here: [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).  Basically, you just need your entire code block unifromly indented four spaces and stackoverflow will automatically format it as code.  All the `{}` button does is move a code block to the right by four spaces.  You can format individual pieces of code by putting a backquote before and after the code segment, but that should not be how you format multi-line code.

Comment: Yes, in browser to get data from a server somewhere, you use an Ajax call from your Javascript.   The older API for that is called [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).  The more modern interface in the browser is called [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).  You can use either, but `fetch()` is generally more streamlined and has newer features.